# Monitor TCP port traffic and get a sound alert when a specific text string is found on Windows

Tags: tcp, wireshark, sniffing

I need to watch a port for several hours and make an audible alert whenever a specific string comes through. Windows only. Is this possible with Wireshark or another sniffer tool or maybe a sniffer tool continuously exporting to text file and another tool watching the file and making the alert sound?

Comment: are you running the server or you just want to "eavesdrop" on the connection?

Comment: Just need to know when another local program running on the same computer gets a specific alert from its server and this other program doesn't provide an API to get this info.